# control hierarchy of position_dodge

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to control which element is plotted in front of the other if one uses dodged bar charts.

```
 ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl), fill=factor(vs))) +
    geom_bar(position= position_dodge (width = - 0.5))
```

[image]

In this example the blue bars are plotted in front of the red ones. Is it possiple to reverse the order without hacking alpha values?

Comment: You can reverse the factor order, but that will also change which one is left and right, I think.

Comment: Hmm, I actually get them the other way around on the dev version.

Comment: changing the data insted of the plot comand is what I would consider hacking ;) I would like to avoid that...

Comment: well then you're often out of luck with ggplot. Very often one has reshape data, for example.

Comment: I know - for my actual data I avoided the problem bu using black and a transparent filling, but I was wondering if there is a more elegenat solution to that problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your control here is limited. Using factor levels we can control i) the `fill` color ordering and ii) the ordering of `position_dodge` using `group`.

Here are the four options:

```
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl), fill = factor(vs, 0:1), group = factor(vs, 0:1))) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width = - 0.5))

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl), fill = factor(vs, 0:1), group = factor(vs, 1:0))) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width = - 0.5))

p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl), fill = factor(vs, 1:0), group = factor(vs, 0:1))) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width = - 0.5))

p4 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl), fill = factor(vs, 1:0), group = factor(vs, 1:0))) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width = - 0.5))

library(cowplot)
plot_grid(p1, p2, p3, p4, align = 'hv')
```

[image]

So it seems only the dodging order is important. In the dev version at least, the right bar is always plotted in front of the left bar.